# access private member using template trick

Tags: c++, templates

From a blog post [*Access to private members: Safer nastiness*](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html) by [Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb):

```
template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type M>
struct Rob { 
  friend typename Tag::type get(Tag) {
    return M;
  }
};

// use
struct A {
  A(int a):a(a) { }
private:
  int a;
};

// tag used to access A::a
struct A_f { 
  typedef int A::*type;
  friend type get(A_f);
};

template struct Rob<A_f, &A::a>;

int main() {
  A a(42);
  std::cout << "proof: " << a.*get(A_f()) << std::endl;
}
```

how `get` function can be call from `a` object since its not defined inside `class A` ?

**EDIT:**

I don't understand why get must have Tag as parameter instead of  `a.*get<A_f>()`
=> ok it's due to ADL mechanism

Comment: Seems to be a weird bug when it comes to Argument Depending Lookup (ADL), I'm currently on my blackberry and can't play around with it - but if that compiles it should (from my point of view) be treated as a bug.

Comment: Has anyone confirmed this to work on any compilers other than gcc?

Comment: @hexist I just verified this on Clang (3.1) and Intel C++ (13.0.0).

Comment: I think the core question is why the compiler doesn't abort on `template struct Rob<A_f, &A::a>;` with something like "A::a is private within this context". After all, the code is trying to get a pointer to a private member. Weird.

Comment: @hexist add Apple LLVM 4.1 to the list that this works on. Seeing a pattern here...

Comment: Very interesting, I would very much like to know why exactly all the compilers think tihs is legal. @NikosChantziaras boiled down the (real imho) question very well.. how is it legal that one can use this to resolve `&A::a` from outside of `A`. I'm wondering if it's an unintended consequence of something defined in the c++ std, or if it's really intended to work like this.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, I think your link is wrong there. Try: http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html

Comment: @bdonlan:  Oops, thanks.  Yes, that's where the code is from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not calling `get` from `a`! Actually what get return is a class pointer to a member inside `A` and type of it is `int A::*` so you need an instance of `A` to access that value.

For example let me play a little with your code:

```
struct A {
    A(int a):a(a) { }
    int b;
private:
    int a;
};
void test() {
    auto p = &A::b;
    std::cout << a.*p << std::endl;
}
```

Did I call `p` from inside `a`? `a` does not have `p`, this is exactly what happened in your code, `get` function return `&A::a` and you use `a` to read its value! that's all, nothing is wrong and I think it will be compiled in all compilers.

One other question here is: Why C++ allow declaring template using private member of `A`. C++ standard say:

> **14.7.2p8** The usual access checking rules do not apply to names used to  specify explicit instantiations. [Note: In particular, the template 
>   arguments and names used in the function declarator (including
>   parameter  types, return types and exception specifications) may be
>   private types or objects which would normally not be accessible and
>   the template may  be a member template or member function which would
>   not normally be  accessible.]

But if you try to instantiate or even `typedef` specified template then you get an error.
Let's modify your example slightly:

```
struct A {
private:
    int a;
    friend void f();
};

// Explicit instantiation - OK, no access checks
template struct Rob<A_f, &A::a>;

// Try to use the type in some way - get an error.
struct Rob<A_f, &A::a> r;            // error
typedef struct Rob<A_f, &A::a> R;    // error
void g(struct Rob<A_f, &A::a>);      // error

// However, it's Ok inside a friend function.
void f() {
    Rob<A_f, &A::a> r;               // OK
    typedef Rob<A_f, &A::a> R;       // OK
}
```

Comment: @stackmonster certainly we have something in common

Comment: However in all normal usage, you can't take the address of a private member, he's getting around that using template trickery.

Comment: the friend get function inside A_f is useless isn't it ?

Comment: @Guillaume07 of course, you can remove it and still get same result

Comment: I don't understand why get should have Tag as parameter

Comment: To pass the type to the `Rob` and make it general, using this technique you can pass any private member of any class to `Rob` and also you can be sure that `get` will remain unique for your tag

Comment: but Rob as already been instantiated with A_f, that trouble me

Comment: thought I can write something like get<A_f>() instead but visual 2012 don't like :/

Comment: You're awesome @BigBoss , 14.7.2p8 (14.7.2p12 in the c++11 spec) clarifies things immensely, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's legal because friend functions are always in the global scope, even if you implement them inside a class. In other words, this:

```
class A
{
    friend void go() {}
};
```

is just a shortcut for:

```
class A
{
    friend void go();
};

void go() {}
```

Comment: But he's friending from outside of A

Comment: thats what he meant by global scope

Comment: You're right, this answer does answer the OP's question about why he can call `get`... although the hidden question that the OP needs to ask is why he can use this trick to resolve `&A::a` from outside of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known compiler bug in gcc and was fixed in a later release.
See-:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41437